# Orange Pi 5 with Ubuntu server - interactivity issues

Tags: orangepi

I have assembled my Orange Pi 5 with SSD and with their image of Ubuntu. It boots and seems to work fine, except one thing. Interactivity. Whether I am typing on real keyboard connected to it or via SSH console, I am getting weird pauses, like 30 seconds and even longer, when it does not seem to anything. But it still accepts or buffers the inputs. Even responds to pings normally.

Does it Orange Pi 5 throttle due to temperature or something? Or could it be the asymmetric CPU architecture and scheduling issue?

```
root@orangepi5:~ # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
root@orangepi5:~ # uname -a
Linux orangepi5 5.10.110-rockchip-rk3588 #1.1.6 SMP Thu Jun 1 21:23:54 CST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `journalctl -f` or `dmesg -w` in a second session might tell you what happens if you type into the first session

Comment: Providing Ubuntu Server product/release details may help, is this a Ubuntu Server install, or Ubuntu Core Server install? and what release of that *unstated* Ubuntu Server product?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your details show a Debian based kernel & Ubuntu based OS and not Ubuntu*